# Minimizing imenu for cperl mode

Tags: imenu, perl

Suppose we have a `Spec_pages.pm` file that looks like this:

```
package WWW::Spec_pages;

sub new
sub get_news
sub spec_page
sub spec_page_subtype
```

When I run `M-x imenu`, I get this:

```
*Rescan*
+Unsorted.List+...
+Packages+...
+Hierarchy+...
WWW::Spec_pages::new
WWW::Spec_pages::get_news
WWW::Spec_pages::spec_page
WWW::Spec_pages::spec_page_subtype
```

Is it possible to remove the unnecessary information and just keep the list of functions:

```
new
get_news
spec_page
spec_page_subtype
```

Maybe, it's also possible to sort them by name?

Answer (score 1):

cperl-mode does not (yet) strip the package name from subroutines.  I think this would be a good idea to add to cperl-mode, at least when there's only one package in the file. Do you want to report-emacs-bug?

As for sorting: cperl-mode honors the value of imenu-sort-function, which can be customized to sort alphabetically.